# Mechanism and recovery of lower back pain?

Tags: recovery, back-pain, physiology, biomechanics

I normally recover from lower back pain just going to run. 
It results from studying too much and sitting - skipping gym and sport during exam weeks.

It alleviates normally after one hour running. 
This time however I tried to alleviate it in interval running (2 x 15 min) and see try again tomorrow (15 min x 2) and see during 3rd day how is the pain.
Very cold water (for whole body, about 30-45 seconds) in Spa centers (colder than from tab) also causes very good burning sensation there in the lower back region. 
Repeating it, shows that the pain sensation gets weaker.
After this the pain also disappears.

In summary methods of alleviating lower back pain

- 1-1.5h hour running (usually requires longer time to relieve)
- interval running during three days (2 x 15 min, 2nd day 2 x 15 min, 3rd day 2 x 15 min)
- very cold water to alleviate it (30-45 seconds for whole body)

I have not found any stretching technique how to alleviate the lower back pain or to increase the blood circulation there.

**How can you stretch the lower back?**

I would like to understand better what is causing the lower back pain to plan better recovery and prevention programs from such pains.

**What is the mechanism causing the lower back pain?**

**What is a good way of alleviating the lower back pain?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Lower back Pain seems to emerge from you studying too much, which means that you don't have a correct posture or proper seat with support. Although you can alleviate the pain, i recommend checking in your posture to prevent future problems such as chronic back pains.
Exercise increases blood flow and boosts muscle activity , hence alleviating pain. You can perform the following stretches to further alleviate and build a stronger back.

1. **Back Extensions** - These are great for building strong back muscles which will inturn boost your overall posture.
   [image: Back Extensions]
2. **Various Core Exercises** - You have to improve your core muscles to have overall stability and balance while doing your Daily activities, stronger core muscles can even prevent further back pains. I recommend all variations of Planks and also all variations of crunches.
   [image: Planks]
3. **Back Stretches** - The muscle gets stiff after being inactive in a chair all day, stretches help increase blood flow and also release of lactic acid after workouts.
   [image: Back Streches]
4. **Foam roller** - This is the ultimate self massage tool. Its my personal favourite and lets you give yourself a deep muscle massage. With the foam roller, you can also massage any muscle. You will also increase your core stability while doing so. The picture below is a popular foam roller by Trigger Point
   [image: Grid Foam Roller]
   Enjoy your workouts!

Comment: Excellent answer! I found also this kind of ball what seems to be good for travelling https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAP93zdP4HM Do you know what is its name so I can buy it from Ebay too? Then there was two types of these Foam rollers from Trigger point (red and green). Is this green good to begin with?

Comment: Dont buy that ball, buy a cheap tennis ball instead, its ten times cheaper and gets the job done just as well. The grid foam roller is a must buy. Its long lasting compared to traditional foam rollers. There is no difference in color, but make sure you get the right size when travelling.

Comment: Which foam rollers are good choices? Just one or two. One for home and one for travelling? Is this Black Standard what you have in the picture good choice? Then there is also Black Mini. Then Black V2 (just longer than standard).

Comment: I personally use the standard for travelling as well as home.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! I just bought one such item (standard one) and cannot wait to get it.

Comment: Those movements of Upper Back 1 and 2 are just outstanding. The first you can do anywhere where you have a chair like in a library. I can feel it easily in increasing the blood circulation there and making the area warm. Those other movements I have done regularly, but not those targeted for upper back. What is the maximal length of doing these movements? I think I read somewhere that 30 seconds when you are blocking blood circulation in an area. I am not sure how it is in these upper back movements.

Comment: Welcome!  Happy to help! 30 seconds per stretch is enough.